# Detect when pullToRefresh is called on swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pull-to-refresh

Is there a way to detect when the `pullToRefresh` has been called on a Parse - `PFQueryTableViewController`?

I've found some of that on objective-c, but nothing on swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `pullToRefresh` is a private implementation, so you can't override it to detect calls. However, pulling to refresh will trigger the `loadObjects` function, which in turn triggers the `objectsWillLoad` and `objectsDidLoad` methods. You can override the 2 methods to do whatever you want to do.

The only drawback is that `objectsWillLoad` and the did load counterpart will be called even when the view is initially displayed.

Comment: Cool, got your logic. Could get it to work placing the objects did load in the right place. Thanks!